# Create multiple Array's dynamically

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Is there any way to create multiple array dynamically as per count.

For example count is 10, then there will be 10 array created dynamically with name array1,array2,array3 ...

Comment: You can use for loop to create number of arrays.

Comment: How ? I'm not getting that.

Comment: I know how to create a for loop but dont know how to create a new array with name according to the "i".

Comment: In Swift you can't create new properties at runtime. Presumably you are coming from a scripting language? The closest you can do is a `Dictionary<String, Array<Int>>`.

Comment: What you probably want to do is create an array of arrays, the name of the array is irrelephant for the execution of the code

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible unlike in PHP, Swift is not an [interpreted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreted_language) language.

Answer (score 0):

All what you need - to create array of arrays. Declaration:

```
var array: [[Any]]!
```

Initialization:

```
let i = 10
array = [[Any]](count: i, repeatedValue: [Any]())
```

Now you access for your arrays, not like `array0`, `array1`, but like `array[0]`, `array[1]`. And there is no way to create truely custom dynamic name variables dynamically.